# Flutter firestore overwrites data when I use set data

Tags: database, upload, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have been trying to add data to sections in my firestorm database, I have a collection -> document -> data fields. Whenever I use setData({'key': 'value'}) is always overwrites the data already in the document. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 4):

That is because what `setData(object)` is used for

> To create or overwrite a single document

While `update(object)`

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document

So what you need is to use `update()`

Comment: Thanks, Ill be sure to use that. But I figured out what I really needed to do was setup a collection inside the documents.

Answer (score 4):

Using `merge: true` in your `setData()` statement prevents overwrite.
This seems similar to the `update()` method but you can use it even when document does not exist (ie is being created).