# new documents gets created even though the user is the same?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, crud

i am trying to upload the value of multiple textfields but firestore keeps resetting all the values so the old ones disappears . i would like to be able to set a value for first textfield (alOne) and maybe come back later and set a value for second textfield(alTwo). but in my case when the second value is set , the first one disappears from firestore?

this is my post function

```
  static void createPostMonday(Post post) async{
await postsRef.document(post.authorId).setData({



  'alOne':post.alOne,
  'alTwo':post.alTwo,
  'alThree':post.alThree,
  'alFour':post.alFour,
  'alFive':post.alFive,
  'alSix':post.alSix,
  'beOne':post.beOne,
  'beTwo':post.beTwo,
  'beThree':post.beThree,
  'beFour':post.beFour,
  'beFive':post.beFive,
  'beSix':post.beSix,
  'likes': post.likes,
  'authorId': post.authorId,
  'timestamp': post.timestamp,
},merge: true);
```

and here is the action(submit) button

```
  _submit() async{
Post post = Post(
  authorId: Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId,
  timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()),
  alOne1: _alOne1,
  alTwo1: _alTwo1,
  alThree1: _alThree1,
  alFour1: _alFour1,
  alFive1: _alFive1,
  alSix1: _alSix1,
  beOne1: _beOne1,
  beTwo1: _beTwo1,
  beThree1: _beThree1,
  beFour1: _beFour1,
  beFive1: _beFive1,
  beSix1: _beSix1,

);
DatabaseService.createPostMonday(post);
Navigator.pop(context);
```

}

and this are 2. of my textfields

```
   Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Alternativ',
              ),
              onChanged: (input) => _alOne1 = input,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Beskrivning',
              ),
              onChanged: (input) => _beOne1 = input,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `setData`, which replaces all existing data in the document with the data you pass in.

If you want to merge the data you're passing in with any existing data that is in the document already, you have two options:

1. Use the [`updateData` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/updateData.html), which updates the document with the data you provide. This write operation will fail if the document doesn't exist yet.
2. Pass in [`{ merge: true }`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) as a second parameter to `setData()`, in which case the data will be merged, and the document will be created if it doesn't exist yet.

I typically use this second approach, as I usually don't know/care whether the document exist already.

---

I just ran this code in one of my apps:

```
var ref = Firestore.instance.collection("chat").document();
ref.setData({ 
    'message': "hello", 
    'timestamp': new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    'uid': (await getUser()).uid 
  }).whenComplete(() {
    ref.setData({ 'message': "hello good welcome"  }, merge: true);
  });
```

So this:

1. Create a new `DocumentReference`
2. Sets three field in this document
3. Then updates one of these fields

After running this code, I have three fields: `timestamp` and `uid` with their value from the original `setData(...)` and `message` with the updated value from `setData(..., merge: true)`.

Comment: hey frank. i think your solution is what i need but i am not sure if i am implementing merge: true the right way, becouse i tried it and still new documents got created?can you show me where to implement it? @frankvanPuffelen

Comment: If you use `setData()` with `{ merge: true }` then the document will be created if it doesn't exist yet. If you don't want that, use `updateData()`. If the code doesn't work as I described, edit your question to show the minimal code of what you tried.

Comment: Unfortunately that your edit makes your question quite different, which means that suddenly my answer makes no sense anymore, because you already incorporated it in there. That's not ideal on Stack Overflow, as we're trying to build a knowledge base here that folks can use in the future too.

Comment: i understand that .  incorporated your answer and what the updated question contains is the results of that, witch brings me back to the same issue! the problem that i hardly am trying to explain is that my firestore fields gets recreated using setData or updateData and i need them to stay so i tried {merge : true} but didnt get any results and the outcome was the same!

Comment: That's not my experience, so I'm not sure what's going on in your case. Can you reproduce the problem in a smaller amount of code that any of us case copy/paste and run?

Comment: im not sure how i could do that! it s not more than what is uploaded in the question. the post function, submit button, and the textfields. thanks by the way

Comment: I updated my answer with a [minimal, complete/standalone example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how fields are merged. At this point I ask that you study that link, and see if you can reproduce the problem in a fragment that is similarly standalone.

Comment: after a lot of searching i came to the this which defines my problem but i stil cant find a solution.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801496/flutter-firestore-overwrites-data-when-i-use-set-data

Comment: We already covered that same here, and my answer describes the two scenarios. But unless you can reproduce a different behavior in a similarly isolated way to the jsbin that I created for you, there's not much I can do to help.

Comment: A jsbin won't work (sorry, I forgot that this is flutter). But unless you can provide a simple snippet we can copy/paste into our project that reproduces the problem, there's not much anyone can do.

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPufflen. sorry i am new to flutter . how can create a simple snippet of my code best way? is there a way for me to make my code (setData) stop overwrite all of the fields ?

Comment: Again: I've shown you the exact Flutter snippet I used, with which I can't reproduce your problem. If you copy/paste my snippet into your app, does it update the document?

Comment: i solved the problem using updateData inside my user documents ! i could not figure out how to connect my post documents to the users so i created the required fields inside the the user documents using update data and everything works perfect ! unfortionatly my user documents fields inside firestore gets a bit messy but i can live with it. thank you for your effort @FrankvanPuffelen